# How to convert a date to a string

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select

I want yo get only the **'date hours:minutes:seconds'** from the Date column

```
Date
10/11/22 12:14:01,807000000
11/12/22 13:15:46,650000000
29/12/22 14:30:46,501000000
```

and I want to get a **string** column with date hours:minutes:seconds

```
Date_string
10/11/22 12:14:01
11/12/22 13:15:46
29/12/22 14:30:46
```

I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
select*, TO_CHAR(extract(hour from (Date)))||':'||TO_CHAR(extract(minute from (Date)))||':'||TO_CHAR(extract(second from (Date))) as Date_string
from table;
```

Comment: if the date format is consistent like it uses 01 instead of 1, then get the left strings; If data is not consistent but consistent with data on the left of the comma, then use REGEXP_SUBSTR to split the string using comma as delimeter

Answer (score 2):

If this is a `date` column, you could use `to_char` directly:

```sql
SELECT m.*, TO_CHAR(my_date_column, 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss')
  FROM mytable m
```

Comment: It doesn't work like this, I got this error: ORA-00907: parenthèse de droite absente
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: @Ruser-lab9 you can retry after adding a comma between argument of the function.

Comment: @Ruser-lab9 yikes! I indeed missed the comma there (shoutout to Barbaros for noticing and editing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEX SUBSTRING function to get the date string on the left.

```
SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR (Date_string, '[^,]+', 1, 1)    
    AS left_part
   FROM Table1;

where ^, means look for chars that are NOT comma on 1st position 
and get the first occurrence (on the left)
```

Result:

```
LEFT_PART
10/11/22 12:14:01
11/12/22 13:15:46
29/12/22 14:30:46
```

reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm

Answer (score 0):

Just do it with the `TO_DATE()` and `TO_CHAR()` function pair, both operating on the Oracle date format strings:

Building the scenario:

```
-- your input ..
WITH indata(dt) AS (
SELECT '10/11/22 12:14:01,807000000' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '11/12/22 13:15:46,650000000' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '29/12/22 14:30:46,501000000' FROM dual
)
-- end of your input. Real query starts here. 
-- Change following comma to "WITH" ..
,
-- Now convert to TIMESTAMP(9) ...
as_ts AS (
  SELECT
    TO_TIMESTAMP(dt ,'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS,FF9') AS ts
  FROM indata
)
SELECT
  ts
, CAST(ts AS TIMESTAMP(0)) AS recast -- note: this is rounded
, TO_CHAR(ts,'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS') AS reformatted -- this is truncated
FROM as_ts
```

Result:

| TS | RECAST | REFORMATTED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10-NOV-22 12.14.01.807000000 | 10-NOV-22 12.14.02 | 10/11/22 12:14:01 |
| 11-DEC-22 13.15.46.650000000 | 11-DEC-22 13.15.47 | 11/12/22 13:15:46 |
| 29-DEC-22 14.30.46.501000000 | 29-DEC-22 14.30.47 | 29/12/22 14:30:46 |

Answer (score 0):

Going by what you have in your question, it appears that the data in the field `Date` is a timestamp. This isn't a problem, but the names of the table (`TABLE`) and field (`Date`) present some challenges.

In Oracle, `TABLE` is a reserved word - so to use it as the name of a table it must be quoted by putting it inside double-quotes, as `"TABLE"`. Similarly, `Date` is a mixed-case identifier and must likewise be quoted (e.g. `"Date"`) every time it's used.

Given the above your query becomes:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR("Date", 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS') AS FORMATTED_DATE
  FROM "TABLE"
```

and produces the desired results. [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/rIxx2YVw)

Generally, it's best in Oracle to avoid using reserved words as identifiers, and to allow the database to convert all names to upper case - if you do that you don't have to quote the names, and you can refer to them by upper or lower case as the database automatically converts all unquoted names to upper case internally.